# How do i handle Nulls in pattern matching in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here is spark shell code

```
 scala> val colName = "time_period_id"


 scala> val df = spark.sql("""select time_period_id from prod.demo where time_period_id = 
 202101102 """)
 df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [time_period_id: int]

 scala>  val result = df.agg(max(colName)).head(1)
 result: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([null])


 scala>     result(0).getInt(0) match {
 |       case null => 0
 |       case _ => result(0).getInt(0)
 |     }
```

If the result  is `Array([null])` then I want `0` to be returned, If the result is `Array([20210110])` then i want `20210110` to be returned

But i am getting this error

```
 <console>:33: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Null(null)
 required: Int
         case null => 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your array item with `lift` in order to deal with it as an Option. It will return Some(null) if the element is null inside, or None if there is no element at all

```
result.lift(0) match {
 case Some(element) if element != null => element.getInt(0)
 case _ => 0
}
```

Or if you don't mind to have more rows in your pattern matching:

```
  result.lift(0) match {
     case Some(null) => 0
     case Some(element) => element.getInt(0)
     case _ => 0
    }
```

Another option is to use `Try`

```
import scala.util.Try
import scala.util.Success

Try(result(0).getInt(0)) match {
  case Success(date) => date
  case _ => 0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the `isNullAt()` method on `result(0)`:

```
scala> val result = Array(org.apache.spark.sql.Row(null))
result: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([null])

scala> result(0) match {
     | case x if x.isNullAt(0) => 0
     | case x => x.getInt(0)
     | }
res0: Int = 0
```